# Could not find method for Android onClick event

Tags: java, android, methods

I've started to learn to code this week. I've been following tutorials about adding events to Google calendar how I've encountered a problem of not being able to find the method. The error is:

> Could not find method onAddEventClicked(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'addEventButton'

This is my code:

```
package com.example.user.plannerv2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.CalendarContract;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Events;
import android.view.View;

public class sub_page01 extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_sub_page01);
    }

    public void onAddEventClicked(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis()  + 60 * 60 * 1000;

        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startTime);
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,endTime);
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, true);

        intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Customer Cabin");
        intent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION,  "Cabin is leased out");
        intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "Cabin");

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Here is my XML;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addEventButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onAddEventClicked"
        android:text="Add Event" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.user.plannerv2, PID: 16127
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onAddEventClicked(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'addEventButton'
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6207)
                      at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11094)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23639)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

As I've said, I'm not 100% sure as I feel the method is being called. Any help would be great.

Comment: You've loaded `R.layout.fragment_sub_page01` into some other class... Besides that, why are you loading a **fragment** layout into an Activity? Try naming your resources better

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
findViewById(R.id.addEventButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        //Perform your action here
    } 
});
```

You are done :)

Comment: This is a Java question, not Xamarin

Comment: @cricket_007 You are very fast in down voting :) Anyway allow me add answer in Java as well:)

Comment: Why would you add it "as well"?

Comment: @cricket_007 Buddy added the answer. If you wish I can remove xamarin code. Can you please rollback your down vote:)

Comment: Well, `this.count` doesn't work there because `this` would refer to the `OnClickListener`, but that's a separate issue

Comment: @cricket_007 Made correction. Thanks for pointing out:) Being a very senior member you should encourage us by pointing out mistakes not by down vote :)

Comment: At least I do both unlike the other person that downvoted.